# What needs to be done to make n_jobs work properly on sklearn? in particular on ElasticNetCV?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, parallel, elastic-net

The constructor of `sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNetCV` takes`n_jobs` as an argument.
Quoting the documentation [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.ElasticNetCV.html?highlight=elasticnetcv)

> n_jobs: int, default=None
>
> Number of CPUs to use during the cross validation. None means 1 unless in a joblib.parallel_backend context. -1 means using all processors. See Glossary for more details.

However, running the below simple program on my 4 core machine (spec details below) shows performance is best when `n_jobs = None`, progressively deteriorating as you increase `n_jobs` all the way to `n_jobs = -1` (supposedly requesting all cores)

```
    import numpy as np
    from sklearn.linear_model import ElasticNetCV

    # ------------- Setup  X, y -------------
    IMPORTANT_K = 10
    TOTAL_K = 30
    SAMPLE_N = 1000
    ERROR_VOL = 1

    np.random.seed(0)
    important_X = np.random.rand(SAMPLE_N, IMPORTANT_K)
    other_X = np.random.rand(SAMPLE_N, TOTAL_K - IMPORTANT_K)
    actual_coefs = np.linspace(0.1, 1, IMPORTANT_K)
    noise = np.random.rand(SAMPLE_N)
    y = important_X @ actual_coefs + noise * ERROR_VOL
    total_X = np.concatenate((important_X, other_X), axis=1)

    # ---------------- Setup ElasticNetCV -----------------
    LASSO_RATIOS = np.linspace(0.01, 1, 10)
    CV = 10

    def enet_fit(X, y, n_jobs: int):
        enet_cv = ElasticNetCV(l1_ratio=LASSO_RATIOS, fit_intercept=True,
                               cv=CV, n_jobs=n_jobs)
        enet_cv.fit(X=X, y=y)
        return enet_cv

    # ------------------- n_jobs test --------------
    N_JOBS = [None, 1, 2, 3, 4, -1]
    import time
    for n_jobs in N_JOBS:
        start = time.perf_counter()
        enet_cv = enet_fit(X=total_X, y=y, n_jobs=n_jobs)
        print('n_jobs = {}, perf_counter = {}'.format(n_jobs, time.perf_counter() - start))
```

### What needs to be done to make this work as expected?

Some people seem to think this is broken in Windows as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56463132/sklearn-n-jobs-1-not-parallelizing-on-windows). Indeed I am running Windows 10 on an Intel i7-7700 4.2Ghz machine, but unfortunately the question the above link points to does not have any commentary or answers, nor unfortunately do I have access to a Unix machine to try if this works on Unix.

Some people [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562465/python-n-jobs-for-large-scale-prob) say running from an interactive session is a problem. I observe the above program perform in the same way whether run on Jupyter Lab or as a script from the terminal.

I will also add that I have run this on several version combinations of sklearn and joblib, but have not been able to resolve the problem in that way.

One of those combinations is below, put together by `conda env create` when only specifying the python version `python==3.6.10` thereby allowing conda to install the versins it deems are most appropriate.
I also include the `numpy`, `mkl` and `scipy` dependencies that were installed.

```
intel-openmp              2020.1                      216
joblib                    0.14.1                     py_0
mkl                       2020.1                      216
mkl-service               2.3.0            py36hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py36h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.1.0            py36h675688f_0
numpy                     1.18.1           py36h93ca92e_0
numpy-base                1.18.1           py36hc3f5095_1
python                    3.6.10               h9f7ef89_2
scikit-learn              0.22.1           py36h6288b17_0
scipy                     1.4.1            py36h9439919_0
```

### The questions

Does the simple program above give you better performance with increasing n_jobs when you run it?

On what OS / setup?

Is there something that must be tweaked for this to work properly?

All help very much appreciated

Comment: Although I am not familiar with scikit learn, this sounds EXACTLY like a problem we currently have with PyTorch where the `num_workers` argument on Windows causes a massive hit to performance instead of helping. You can even look at the github issue that is labeled high priority and has been open since 2018!!

Comment: Would you be able to confirm that `num_workers` improves performance on Unix (or variants) as expected and that you only have the problem on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having profiled and stepped through sklearn´s code, I´ve got some answers.

### The summary:

Contrary to what has been suggested, `sklearn`'s `ElasticNetCV()`'s poor scalability to `n_jobs`  is not due to:

- the overhead of launching threads or processes.
- `SequentialBackend` always being used irrespective of `n_jobs`. *(I cannot reproduce this problem as stated in n1tk's answer, However I can confirm that `SequentialBackend` is used whenever `n_jobs = 1`, irrespective of the actual context backend. Rather than a bug, this seems to be reasonable behavior)*

The actual problem is `sklearn`'s `ElasticNetCV`'s default use of the `threading` `parallel_backend`, while the tasks it sends into `joblib`'s `Parallel()` for parallelization spend most of their time holding onto the GIL.

Clearly this is counterproductive.

The above is true of the OP's problem size of `n=1000` and `k=30`. Once `n` or `k` grow very large, then the coordinate descent algorithm, the only code running outside the GIL, begins to crunch enough cycles for threading to bring execution time down relative to sequential.

This means that for problems taking about a second to solve, `sklearn`'s out of the box parallelism doesn't help. And if you have 10,000 of these problems to solve at any one time, you are going to have to find another parallelism solution or wait for the best part of three hours between runs.

This situation can be significantly improved in various ways with varying degrees of effort vs returns.

### The detail

The ElasticNetCV call stack goes something like this:

```
ElasticNetCV.fit()
    Parallel(...)
        _path_residuals(...)
            enet_path(...)
                cd_fast.enet_coordinate_descent_gram(...)
```

It's not until `cd_fast.enet_coordinate_descent_gram()` that the GIL is released. You can see the `with nogil:` statement [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/_cd_fast.pyx)

`%prun` shows that 99.3% of the time in this stack is spent in `Parallel(...)`

`%lprun` shows that only 40% of this time is spent in `cd_fast.enet_coordinate_descent_gram(...)`

The remaining 60% of the time spent in `Parallel(...)`, is spent under the GIL, and is hence un-parallelizable.

A back of the envelope calculation suggests that the 40% parallelizable code should allow 2 threads (more than 2 would not help) to complete the 100 tasks into which this problem is broken down in 60%*99 + 1% = 60.4% of sequential time.

So why is the actual performance of n_jobs = 2 worse than that of n_jobs = 1?

I'm not sure, but on my 4 core machine (8 logical), `n_jobs = 2` spawns 8 extra threads rather than just one extra thread (or two workers). With 60% of the execution un-parallelizable, this could simply cause an oversubscription problem. I do see a very large jump in kernel activity to around 50% of CPU usage in task manager when `n_jobs = 2`. This suggests oversubscription.

I don't yet know why setting `n_jobs = 2`, results in 8 additional threads, rather than just one (or two workers).

### The simplest solution

The problem can be alleviated to some extent by instructing `joblib` to switch to the `loky` multi-processing backend.

This is done using `with`

```
with parallel_backend('loky'):
    ElasticNetCV.fit(...)
```

On my 4 core (8 logical) machine, the most improvement using `loky` is achieved with `n_jobs = -1` (equivalent to `n_jobs = 8`). This achieves a x2.7 performance improvement. That is some way off the x4 improvement I'd expect from fully parallelizable cython code on 4 cores (8 logical) and which I get on this machine on such code.

Perhaps this is because `loky` is not entirely immune to oversubscription. Its spawned processes themselves spawn threads (2 additional threads in the original process and 4 threads on each sub-process on my 4 core machine). These threads compete for their process's GIL. Nevertheless, as there are more GILs to go around (one per spawned process) the performance is better than with the default `threading` backend.

It is also certain that process spawning and communication overhead contribute to the gap in performance between x2.7 and x4.

Finally, I am not sure how well this solution scales to 32 cores compared with a properly functioning multithreaded solution. **I'd be grateful for commentary from someone able to run the OP's script on a 32 core machine using the simple `with parallel_backend('loky'):` fix.**

For those who want more performance, or are irked by parallel infrastructure being sent un-parallelizable tasks, read on.

### Fixing sklearn

There is a bug in `sklearn`'s `coordinate_descent.py` whereby `ElasticNetCV.fit(...)` ultimately calls `enet_path()` without setting `check_input = False`. The checks are redundant once execution gets to `enet_path()` and indeed the docs suggest setting `check_input = False` if the caller has already ensured what is being checked. It seems that in this instance, `sklearn` have not followed their own advice, and have failed to implement this in `ElasticNetCV`'s case.

Fixing this bug cuts the non-parallelizable time from 60% to 30%  and the total running time by 40% when running sequentially.

Yet the `threading` backend continues to be incapable of improving performance despite now only 30% of the execution time being un-parallelizable. Again, a back of the envelope calculation suggests 4 cores could be put to use here on our 100 subtasks, and complete in around 30% of sequential execution time. In practice however, 8 new threads are spawned when `n_jobs = 2`, and 4 additional threads for every further `n_jobs` unit increment. The end result is slower calculation times for `n_jobs > 1`, and the accompanying symptom of kernel dominating CPU usage (between 50% to 80%).

Once again, this suggests oversubscription as a result of too many threads competing for the same GIL. Once again I don't yet know why the threading backend spawns this seemingly over-inflated number of threads. **Anyone know?**

Performance using `loky` is also enhanced by this fix, with diminishing returns as you increase `n_jobs`. On my 8 core machine I got to x3.7 of the out of the box sklearn sequential time by setting `n_jobs = 8` with the `check_input = False` fix. Note that this is only x2 of the `check_input = False` sequential time, and that a properly working multi threaded solution would give us approx x4.

A caveat, and perhaps the reason why `check_input = False` has not been implemented in the official `sklearn` release. The input checks for `MutiTaskElasticNet` are only performed inside `enet_path()`, and they would need to be re-factored elsewhere for this fix not to potentially break the `MultiTask` version of the algorithm. However, as far as I can tell, the single output version will work fine without having to worry about this.

### Other issues:

The tasks passed into `Parallel(...)` call `np.dot(X.T, X)` inside the GIL for each fold and (unnecessarily) for each `l1_ratio`. The unnecessary calculations could be removed and the necessary ones re-factored out of `Parallel(...)`. according to my profiler, this would further reduce the GIL time of parallel tasks from 30% to 20%.

Ultimately, you don't want code subject to GIL going into `Parallel(...)` with a threading backend. You can either take things out, or cythonsize `with nogil:` the things you put in.

Comment: So this is nothing else then my answer, pointing that default parallel part used threading part, you just went to confirm that and based on execution and verbose this is the problem, no matter the size of the data we do see sequential. I did implement pure “joblib” approach and improvement skyrocketed with 100mil samples. So is a bug when using threading and GIL is on threading part and is clearly stated on “joblib” documentation that this behavior is expected. Also not everything will work in parallel.  In conclusion you just confirmed my findings with “loky” backend.

Comment: The reason that “n_jobs=1” better performance compared with “n_jobs=2” is because of the copy/accessing of data(cached and checkpoint) in memory for each job. As side note: Sequential part is also a problem in gpu RNNs when using for NLP and this where does come in place parallel to solve it aka transformers or simply said “attention mechanism”.

Comment: Thank you so much for this helpful answer! I'm running into the issue that you debug in the **FIxing sklearn** section, and I'm hoping to implement your fix. When you call `enet_model.path` so that you can set `check_input=False`, do you call that before or after `enet_model.fit`?

Answer (score 3):

When I ran your script, I got the same impression, that `n_jobs` was hurting you performance. However, you have to consider that parallelizing the cross-validation would only benefit if you have more data samples. With few data, the communication overhead indeed is more expensive than the processing cost involved on the task.

I tried your script with more samples `SAMPLE_N = 100000` and got the following results. Setup: macos i5 8gb.

```
n_jobs = None, perf_counter = 21.605680438
n_jobs = 1, perf_counter = 22.555127251
n_jobs = 2, perf_counter = 15.129894496000006
n_jobs = 3, perf_counter = 11.280528144999998
n_jobs = 4, perf_counter = 13.050180971000003
n_jobs = -1, perf_counter = 20.031103849000004
```

Comment: Interesting, I am grateful for you trying this out. I wonder how `n_jobs= -1` is different to `n_jobs=4` on my 4 core machine. what OS / cores / setup are you running this on? I too can now see the parallelism kicking in by increasing to 100,000 samples. Thanks for that. 12 seconds for n_jobs=None and 5 seconds for n_jobs=-1 which is now fastest on my setup. Who has 100,000 samples from the same DGP though? Do you know exactly what sklearn is doing to cause the overhead to be so large?

Comment: Is it spawning processes or threads?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, sklearn prefer threads. Actually, the overhead it's quite normal to happen when you distribute tasks. Maybe for samples=1000, it's reasonable to say that it's more costly to create and destroy more and more threads than to calculate the cv itself. In parallel operations, it's normal to reach an optimal number of workers *depending on the sample size* and after this, the cpu strives to manage the workers more than workers are working.

Comment: You'll see this better when you have 10 interns directly under your guidance haha.

Comment: mmm ok. I had the perception (uneducated admittedly) that sklearn preferred to spawn processes given the python GIL, and that threads was a relatively recent addition (since sklearn 0.14 ?)Presumably for threads to bring computation times down they must somehow get around the GIL. At any rate I would have thought that a properly implemented thread pool with threads at the ready to run on separate cores would be able to speed up this problem, even with 1000 samples. Each L1_ratio path can be distributed to a different core. I am still surprised.

Comment: Not sure what the overhead is of copying a 1,000 x 31 matrix to L3 cache for the cores to share (if the matrix is not already there) but it can't be much. when I do `%timeit X_copy = np.copy(total_X)` it tells me the call takes 8.74 micro seconds. That's about 1 hundred thousandth of the approx 1 second it takes to perform the CV on that matrix. What other things do you think are causing overhead?

Answer (score 2):

Would try to answer based on experience and understandings of parallel computing in production for DS/ML models:

> Answer to your questions as high level:

1. Does the simple program above give you better performance with increasing n_jobs when you run it? `answer: Yes and can be seen bellow in results.`
2. On what OS / setup? `answer: OS:ubuntu, 2xCPUsx16Cores+512GB RAM with python=3.7, joblib>=0.14.1 and sklearn >=0.22.1`
3. Is there something that must be tweaked for this to work properly? `yes: change/force parallel_backend to be used other then sequential (requires joblib approach with registered parallel_backend and you can use sklearn.utils.parallel_backend ... I tried sequential from sklearn model you have with n_jobs=-1 into joblib Parallel and got huge scale but need to look more for correctness but did saw huge improvement when scaled to 100mil samples on my machine so worth to test it since were amazed by performance with predefined backend`.

> My conda setup:

```
scikit-image              0.16.2           py37h0573a6f_0  
scikit-learn              0.22.1           py37hd81dba3_0  
ipython                   7.12.0           py37h5ca1d4c_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  
msgpack-python            0.6.1            py37hfd86e86_1  
python                    3.7.6                h357f687_2    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0  
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
joblib                    0.14.1                     py_0
```

---

> Try to leave 1 core for your machine if you use personal machine or
>   workstation with `n_jobs=-2`, you can increase you data because this
>   is the purpose of joblib for optimization (not all algorithms support
>   this approach but is out of scope here) and also change the backend
>   because by default won't perform parallel tasks and would only use
>   sequential, maybe with more data is doing an auto "mode" but not sure
>   about it based since I tested with 1k, 10k 100k, 1 mil and 10 mil
>   samples and without loky backend ElasticNetCV won't go out of
>   sequential backend.

---

> **Joblib** is optimized to be fast and robust on large data in particular and has specific optimizations for numpy arrays.

As an explanation will look into how is calculated `resources`:

> For n_jobs below -1, (n_cpus + 1 + n_jobs) are used. Thus for n_jobs
>   = -2, all CPUs but one are used. None is a marker for ‘unset’ that will be interpreted as n_jobs=1 (sequential execution)
>
> **Your code perform bad with `n_jobs=-1` so try `n_jobs=-2` due following facts:**

1. does use all your **CPU cores** (based on documentation) but you can change to be used **threads** by registering a **parallel_backend** from **joblib** of your machine so this
   will be slow and will decrease performance if other processes does use CPU
   threads/cores (in your case this is happening( you have OS running and other processes that needs CPU power to run) and also is not taking full advantage of "threading" so does use "cores" based on your performance issue.

As an example you will use the `"n_jobs=-1"` when on cluster mode so the workers as a container does have allocated cores for and will take advantage of `parallel approach` and `distribute` **optimization or computation** part.

2. you run out of CPU resources in this case and also don’t forget that
   parallel isn’t `“cheap”`  *because does copy SAME data for each
       “job” so you will get all that “allocation” at the same time*.
3. sklearn parallel implementation isn't perfect so in your case will try to use *n_jobs=-2* or if you want to use *joblib* then you can have more room of optimizing the algorithm. Your CV part is where all performance does get degraded because will be `parallelized`.

> Will add the following from joblib to better understand how does work in your case and limitations + differences:

```
backend: str, ParallelBackendBase instance or None, default: ‘loky’

    Specify the parallelization backend implementation. Supported backends are:

        “loky” used by default, can induce some communication and memory overhead when exchanging input and output data with the worker Python processes.
        “multiprocessing” previous process-based backend based on multiprocessing.Pool. Less robust than loky.
        “threading” is a very low-overhead backend but it suffers from the Python Global Interpreter Lock if the called function relies a lot on Python objects. “threading” is mostly useful when the execution bottleneck is a compiled extension that explicitly releases the GIL (for instance a Cython loop wrapped in a “with nogil” block or an expensive call to a library such as NumPy).
        finally, you can register backends by calling register_parallel_backend. This will allow you to implement a backend of your liking.
```

> From source code the implementation I do see that sklearn does use **cores** or is **preferred but not default** for all algorithms the **threads**: [_joblib.py](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/483cd3eaa3c636a57ebb0dc4765531183b274df0/sklearn/utils/_joblib.py)

```py
    import warnings as _warnings

    with _warnings.catch_warnings():
        _warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
        # joblib imports may raise DeprecationWarning on certain Python
        # versions
        import joblib
        from joblib import logger
        from joblib import dump, load
        from joblib import __version__
        from joblib import effective_n_jobs
        from joblib import hash
        from joblib import cpu_count, Parallel, Memory, delayed
        from joblib import parallel_backend, register_parallel_backend


    __all__ = ["parallel_backend", "register_parallel_backend", "cpu_count",
               "Parallel", "Memory", "delayed", "effective_n_jobs", "hash",
               "logger", "dump", "load", "joblib", "__version__"]
```

> But your listed `Elastic Net model` algorithm on the `CV` part does used "threads" as preferred (_joblib_parallel_args(prefer="threads")) and seems is a bug for windows that does only consider **cores**:

```py
    mse_paths = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs, verbose=self.verbose,
                         **_joblib_parallel_args(prefer="threads"))(jobs)
```

> **Note:** This answer is from experience from daily basis working to take advantage of `sparkjoblib` and `parallel_backend('spark')` and
>   `parallel_backend('dask')`. Scales and run fast as expected but don't
>   forget that each executor I do have is basically with 4 cores and
>   4-32GB RAM so when doing `n_jobs=-1` does take parallel part of joblib
>   tasks inside of each executor and that **copy SAME data** won't be
>   noticed since is distributed.

Does run perfectly CV and fit part, and i do use `n_jobs=-1` when performing *fit* or *CV* parts.

---

**My results with OP default setup:**

> ## # Without tracking/progress execution is faster execution but needed to add progress for clarity:

```
    n_jobs = None, perf_counter = 1.4849148329813033 ([Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.)
    n_jobs = 1, perf_counter = 1.4728297910187393 ([Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.)
    n_jobs = 2, perf_counter = 1.470994730014354 ([Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.)
    n_jobs = 4, perf_counter = 1.490676686167717 ([Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.)
    n_jobs = 8, perf_counter = 1.465600558090955 ([Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.)
    n_jobs = 12, perf_counter = 1.463360101915896 ([Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.)
    n_jobs = 16, perf_counter = 1.4638906640466303 ([Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.)
    n_jobs = 20, perf_counter = 1.4602260519750416 ([Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.)
    n_jobs = 24, perf_counter = 1.4646347570233047 ([Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.)
    n_jobs = 28, perf_counter = 1.4710926250554621 ([Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.)
    n_jobs = -1, perf_counter = 1.468439529882744 ([Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.)
    n_jobs = -2, perf_counter = 1.4649679311551154 ([Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.)
```

> ## # With tracking/progress execution needed to add progress+verbose for clarity:

```
0%|          | 0/12 [00:00<?, ?it/s][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    2.9s finished
  8%|▊         | 1/12 [00:02<00:31,  2.88s/it][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
n_jobs = None, perf_counter = 2.8790326060261577
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    2.8s finished
 17%|█▋        | 2/12 [00:05<00:28,  2.87s/it][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
n_jobs = 1, perf_counter = 2.83856769092381
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    2.8s finished
 25%|██▌       | 3/12 [00:08<00:25,  2.85s/it][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
n_jobs = 2, perf_counter = 2.8207667160313576
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    2.8s finished
 33%|███▎      | 4/12 [00:11<00:22,  2.84s/it][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
n_jobs = 4, perf_counter = 2.8043343869503587
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    2.7s finished
 42%|████▏     | 5/12 [00:14<00:19,  2.81s/it][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
n_jobs = 8, perf_counter = 2.730375789105892
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    2.9s finished
 50%|█████     | 6/12 [00:16<00:16,  2.82s/it][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
n_jobs = 12, perf_counter = 2.8604282720480114
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    2.8s finished
 58%|█████▊    | 7/12 [00:19<00:14,  2.83s/it][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
n_jobs = 16, perf_counter = 2.847634136909619
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    2.8s finished
 67%|██████▋   | 8/12 [00:22<00:11,  2.84s/it][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
n_jobs = 20, perf_counter = 2.8461739809717983
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    2.9s finished
 75%|███████▌  | 9/12 [00:25<00:08,  2.85s/it][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
n_jobs = 24, perf_counter = 2.8684673600364476
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    2.9s finished
 83%|████████▎ | 10/12 [00:28<00:05,  2.87s/it][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
n_jobs = 28, perf_counter = 2.9122865139506757
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    3.1s finished
 92%|█████████▏| 11/12 [00:31<00:02,  2.94s/it][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
n_jobs = -1, perf_counter = 3.1204342890996486
[Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    3.3s finished
100%|██████████| 12/12 [00:34<00:00,  2.91s/it]
n_jobs = -2, perf_counter = 3.347235122928396
```

> HERE MAGIC starts:
>
> So I would say this is actually the bug, even if does is specified the
>   n_jobs this won't take effect and is still runs as 'None' or '1'.
>   Small differences in time is probably due Caching the results using
>   [joblib.Memory](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/memory_basic_usage.html#how-to-use-joblib-memory) and [Checkpoint](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/nested_parallel_memory.html#checkpoint-using-joblib-memory-and-joblib-parallel) but need to look more on this
>   part in source code (I bet is implemented otherwise will be expensive
>   to be performed CV).
>
> As a reference: this is by using **joblib** and do **parallel part** with **parallel_backend**: results with specifying [parallel_backend('loky')](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.parallel_backend.html) in order to have the ability to specify the default backend used by **Parallel** inside with block and not used **'auto'** mode:
>
> ## # Without tracking/progress execution is faster execution but needed to add progress for clarity:

```
n_jobs = None, perf_counter = 1.7306506633758545, sec
n_jobs = 1, perf_counter = 1.7046034336090088, sec
n_jobs = 2, perf_counter = 2.1097865104675293, sec
n_jobs = 4, perf_counter = 1.4976494312286377, sec
n_jobs = 8, perf_counter = 1.380277156829834, sec
n_jobs = 12, perf_counter = 1.3992164134979248, sec
n_jobs = 16, perf_counter = 0.7542541027069092, sec
n_jobs = 20, perf_counter = 1.9196209907531738, sec
n_jobs = 24, perf_counter = 0.6940577030181885, sec
n_jobs = 28, perf_counter = 0.780998945236206, sec
n_jobs = -1, perf_counter = 0.7055854797363281, sec
n_jobs = -2, perf_counter = 0.4049191474914551, sec
Completed
```

> Below output will explain EVERYTHING about limitations you do have, "IMPRESSION of paralel expected vs paralell done insklearn algorithm you have" and in general what is executing and how may workers are assigned:
>
> ## # With tracking/progress execution needed to add progress+verbose for clarity:

```
0%|          | 0/12 [00:00<?, ?it/s][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
    [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    3.4s finished
8%|▊         | 1/12 [00:03<00:37,  3.44s/it][Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Using backend SequentialBackend with 1 concurrent workers.
        ......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

n_jobs = None, perf_counter = 3.4446191787719727, sec

 [Parallel(n_jobs=1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    3.5s finished
 17%|█▋        | 2/12 [00:06<00:34,  3.45s/it]

n_jobs = 1, perf_counter = 3.460832357406616, sec

[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 2 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    2.0s finished
 25%|██▌       | 3/12 [00:09<00:27,  3.09s/it]

n_jobs = 2, perf_counter = 2.2389445304870605, sec

[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 4 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=4)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    1.7s finished
 33%|███▎      | 4/12 [00:10<00:21,  2.71s/it]

n_jobs = 4, perf_counter = 1.8393192291259766, sec

[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 8 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Done  34 tasks      | elapsed:    1.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=8)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    1.3s finished
 42%|████▏     | 5/12 [00:12<00:16,  2.36s/it]

n_jobs = 8, perf_counter = 1.517085075378418, sec

[Parallel(n_jobs=12)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 12 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=12)]: Done  26 tasks      | elapsed:    1.3s
[Parallel(n_jobs=12)]: Done  77 out of 100 | elapsed:    1.5s remaining:    0.4s
[Parallel(n_jobs=12)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    1.6s finished
 50%|█████     | 6/12 [00:14<00:13,  2.17s/it]

n_jobs = 12, perf_counter = 1.7410166263580322, sec

[Parallel(n_jobs=16)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 16 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=16)]: Done  18 tasks      | elapsed:    0.1s
[Parallel(n_jobs=16)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    0.7s finished
 58%|█████▊    | 7/12 [00:15<00:09,  1.81s/it]

n_jobs = 16, perf_counter = 0.9577205181121826, sec

[Parallel(n_jobs=20)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 20 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=20)]: Done  10 tasks      | elapsed:    1.6s
[Parallel(n_jobs=20)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    1.9s finished
 67%|██████▋   | 8/12 [00:17<00:07,  1.88s/it]

n_jobs = 20, perf_counter = 2.0630648136138916, sec

[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 24 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done   2 tasks      | elapsed:    0.0s
[Parallel(n_jobs=24)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    0.5s finished
 75%|███████▌  | 9/12 [00:18<00:04,  1.55s/it]

n_jobs = 24, perf_counter = 0.7588121891021729, sec

[Parallel(n_jobs=28)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 28 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=28)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    0.6s finished
 83%|████████▎ | 10/12 [00:18<00:02,  1.34s/it]

n_jobs = 28, perf_counter = 0.8542406558990479, sec

[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 32 concurrent workers.
[Parallel(n_jobs=-1)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    0.7s finished
 92%|█████████▏| 11/12 [00:19<00:01,  1.21s/it][Parallel(n_jobs=-2)]: Using backend LokyBackend with 31 concurrent workers.

n_jobs = -1, perf_counter = 0.8903687000274658, sec

[Parallel(n_jobs=-2)]: Done 100 out of 100 | elapsed:    0.5s finished
100%|██████████| 12/12 [00:20<00:00,  1.69s/it]

n_jobs = -2, perf_counter = 0.544947624206543, sec

# # Here I do show what is doing behind and to understand differences in times and wil explain 'None' vs '1' execution time (is all about picklink process and Memory Caching implementation for paralel. 
[Parallel(n_jobs=-2)]: Done  71 out of 100 | elapsed:    0.9s remaining:    0.4s
Pickling array (shape=(900,), dtype=int64).
Pickling array (shape=(100,), dtype=int64).
Pickling array (shape=(100,), dtype=float64).
Pickling array (shape=(1000, 30), dtype=float64).
Pickling array (shape=(1000,), dtype=float64).
Pickling array (shape=(900,), dtype=int64).
Pickling array (shape=(100,), dtype=int64).
Pickling array (shape=(100,), dtype=float64).
Pickling array (shape=(1000, 30), dtype=float64).
Pickling array (shape=(1000,), dtype=float64).
Pickling array (shape=(900,), dtype=int64).
Pickling array (shape=(100,), dtype=int64).
Pickling array (shape=(100,), dtype=float64).
Pickling array (shape=(1000, 30), dtype=float64).
Pickling array (shape=(1000,), dtype=float64).
Pickling array (shape=(900,), dtype=int64).
Pickling array (shape=(100,), dtype=int64).
Pickling array (shape=(100,), dtype=float64).
[Parallel(n_jobs=-2)]: Done  73 out of 100 | elapsed:    0.9s remaining:    0.3s
Completed
```

---

[n_jobs in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-n-jobs)
[Parallelism in sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computing.html#parallelism)
[Thread-based parallelism vs process-based parallelism](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parallel.html#thread-based-parallelism-vs-process-based-parallelism)

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer. So you are saying that although sklearn specifies `prefer="threads"`, there is a bug in Windows preventing this preference from assigning tasks to threads, resulting in new python processes being spawned instead. Did I understand correctly? Is this resolvable somehow (other than by moving to Unix)?

Comment: Assuming that due the failure to utilize laptop resources but you can open a bug report and provide all info about environment and developers ca point or look into that issue. On linux or spark cluster I didn’t saw or able to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. It would be really helpful if you could clarify whether or not my understanding of your answer is correct. Namely you are saying that although sklearn specifies prefer="threads", there is a bug in Windows preventing this expressed preference from assigning tasks to threads, resulting in new python processes being spawned instead. Did I understand correctly? How do you know there is a bug in Windows?

Comment: It would also really appreciate if you could post the results you get from running the question's script on your Unix box. We could all then see the performance improvement we should expect from sklearn's parallelization of their ElasticNetCV

Comment: added results and content. And yes: I do think is a bug on this algorithm you use because n_jobs won't matter if we specify because will still use SequentialBackend and seems is not related only to Windows but in general ( in distributed computing I do use only parallel_backend and does not suffer from this limitation). Hope I answered all questions.

Comment: Wow, ok, How many cores in your setup? Over how many CPUs / sockets? What OS? If I understand correctly you are saying that `loki` (which spawns processes) actually performs better than `threading` as a result of threading always using 1 thread no matter what. Have I understood what you are saying correctly?

Comment: Interestingly, your results seem to show that `loki` with `n_jobs=1` performs differently (and better) to `threading` with `n_jobs=1`. I would have expected them both to run on the calling thread without parallelism and therefore give near identical results. Why is that not the case?

Comment: Also, I don't think my setup suffers from `n_jobs` not being taken into account. I get markedly different timings for each `n_jobs`, and indeed `n_jobs=-1` gives the best performance if I increase the sample count from 1,000 to 100,000 as stated in the comments to another answer. So it seems that some kind of parallelism is performed just not very effectively, at least on my setup, (as described in the OP). Would you be able to specify the details of the setup you used to run your test, including CPU details, OS and python / package versions?

Comment: @OldSchool I added all requested info and details with progress and tracking to show diferences. : my env and setup is at beginning. Detailed execution to proove that the parallel from ElasticNetCV is not working as intended also take a look of the Pickling array to better point the difference in the execution time when is done in parallel. I tried my best to explain everything and will open a bug/issue report based on this when will get a bit more time.

Comment: @OldSchool Will be better to be implemented control of backed into function/algorithms CV in sklearn too. Hope all helps and my "hard work" and answer all your questions also I do use Xeon CPUs.

Comment: @OldSchool please take a look at execution reports specially "concurrent workers' for what really need to do the parallel when is implemented correctly.

Comment: So, on your setup:
1 - despite parallel_backend properly set up, and despite sklearn setting `**_joblib_parallel_args(prefer="threads")`, SequentialBackend is nevertheless called - no parallelism. 
2 – In contrast, specifying “loky” instead of “threads” does lead to LokyBackend being used with speed improvements:
2 cores - x1.5 
4 cores – x1.9
8 cores – x2.3
16 cores – x3.6
Etc..
Presumably, this is slow because of the process overhead in “loky”?
16 same CPU cores should do this problem at x12(ish) speed in a working “threads” implementation. 
Have I correctly understood you?

Comment: Correct. Since for None goes to actually’1’ nothing gets paralleled since is just 1 worker assigned to do the task. For the other ones is performing in parallel but like pointed at the end of results is involved also I will do a test with memory cached and checkpoints to see if I can gain any improvement at a later time but I can tell you for sure that my setup is similar to how works in distributed environments too (executors are generated by master node and each executor does execute jobs/tasks in parallel). Please let me know if does help my comment.

Comment: @OldSchool, also with large data(100k or 10 mil performance) is more visible( min 10 times)  the performance but if I do post that part too then the answer is becoming too long and is out of scope here ... please let me know if I answered all your questions.